# Why isn't list of elements showing up?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I am working on an AngularJS [tutorial](http://jptacek.com/2013/10/angularjs-introducing-ng-repeat/)

This tutorial covers the ng-repeat directive, an AngularJS directive used repeating data.

To show an example of ng-repeat, The author enters periodic table elements in a JSON format, covering element's name, element #, etc into controller logic($scope)

To display the elements(code below), the author simply used the directive with a html un-ordered list

```
<ul>
  <li data-ng-repeat="element in periodic.elements">{{element.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

I tried doing the same [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3fs5esc/) but the list of elements isn't showing up, only {{element.name}}

At first I thought this was an AngularJS syntax issue but I checked over the scope attribute, if the controller names match, etc....   I made sure to enable the AngularJS option in JsFiddle as well.

Does anyone know what the issue is or why this list isn't showing up?

Comment: When developing JS you are pretty much relying on the browser console to dump errors for you. If you F12 - console your jsfiddle (and run the code) you'd get "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", clicking the location of that error would highlight the end of your script :)

Comment: @JimL  F12 doesnn't work for me, just turns up my screen brightness. Where did you see that error/console? All I see is html output. I tried googling but didn't find a dedicated JsFiddle console

Comment: I was referring to your browsers console, how it functions depends on the browser you are using. It's extremely helpful when working with js/css so I strongly suggest you read up on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget completing controller sytax '});' at the end of the code.

```
'use strict';
var chemistryApp = angular.module('chemistryApp', []);

chemistryApp.controller(
      'chemistryController',
    function chemistryController($scope) {
        $scope.periodic = {elements: [
            {
                "atomicNumber": 1,
                "name": "Hydrogen",
                "atomicWeight": 1.00794,
                "phase": "Gas",
                "ionization": 13.5984,
                "melting": -259.15,
                "boiling": -252.87
            },
            {
                "atomicNumber": 2,
                "name": "Helium",
                "atomicWeight": 4.002602,
                "phase": "Gas",
                "ionization": 24.5874,
                "melting": 0,
                "boiling": -268.93
            },
            {
                "atomicNumber": 3,
                "name": "Lithium",
                "atomicWeight": 6.941,
                "phase": "Solid",
                "ionization": 5.3917,
                "melting": 180.54,
                "boiling": 1342
            }
        ]
       };
    });
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucqsted6/)

Comment: Thanks! It was that closing paranthesis

Comment: yup accept the answer if it is appropriate for you :)