# Why does the filter hide all of the elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am following an Angular JS [tutorial](http://jptacek.com/2013/10/angularjs-introducing-ng-repeat/)

This builds off my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272679/why-isnt-list-of-elements-showing-up)

With some debugging I figured out my last issue and was able to display the list of element names. Now I am working on the next feature of the tutorial - filtering the names based on input from the user.

Heres the lines of code that the author wrote to accomplish this

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="elementName"/>
<li data-ng-repeat="element in periodic.elements ' filter:elementName">
```

He demoed this feature working as well in the tutorial.

Here is my attempt at following his code : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5Lwofmw/)

I made sure to include all the lines of that the author wrote. What's weird here is that when I add the 
" ' filter:elementName "  attribute, it made the list of element names disappear.

Does anyone why that list is disappearing when that attribute is added or how to fix this(I'am new to AngularJS)? I made I didn't type in anything wrong by copying what the author had as well.

Comment: change the single quote for a pipe `|` character (before the filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `|` not a `'`:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="elementName"/>
<li data-ng-repeat="element in periodic.elements | filter:elementName">
```

```js
var chemistryApp = angular.module('chemistryApp', []);
//to turn on strict syntax checking
'use strict';
//Referning module from js file
chemistryApp.controller(
  //name of the controller 
  'chemistryController',
  /* $scope is how you communicate with the view. Scope exposes
    the model to the view. The view can bind to properties and functions
    on the scope.   */
  //function is the actual controller
  function chemistryController($scope) {
    $scope.periodic = {
      elements: [{
        "atomicNumber": 1,
        "name": "Hydrogen",
        "atomicWeight": 1.00794,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 13.5984,
        "melting": -259.15,
        "boiling": -252.87
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 2,
        "name": "Helium",
        "atomicWeight": 4.002602,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 24.5874,
        "melting": 0,
        "boiling": -268.93
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 3,
        "name": "Lithium",
        "atomicWeight": 6.941,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.3917,
        "melting": 180.54,
        "boiling": 1342
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 4,
        "name": "Beryllium",
        "atomicWeight": 9.012182,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 9.3227,
        "melting": 1287,
        "boiling": 2470
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 5,
        "name": "Boron",
        "atomicWeight": 10.811,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.298,
        "melting": 2075,
        "boiling": 4000
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 6,
        "name": "Carbon",
        "atomicWeight": 12.0107,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 11.2603,
        "melting": 3550,
        "boiling": 4027
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 7,
        "name": "Nitrogen",
        "atomicWeight": 14.0067,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 14.5341,
        "melting": -210.1,
        "boiling": -195.79
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 8,
        "name": "Oxygen",
        "atomicWeight": 15.9994,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 13.6181,
        "melting": -218.3,
        "boiling": -182.9
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 9,
        "name": "Fluorine",
        "atomicWeight": 18.9984032,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 17.4228,
        "melting": -219.6,
        "boiling": -188.12
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 10,
        "name": "Neon",
        "atomicWeight": 20.1797,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 21.5645,
        "melting": -248.59,
        "boiling": -246.08
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 11,
        "name": "Sodium",
        "atomicWeight": 22.98977,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.1391,
        "melting": 97.72,
        "boiling": 883
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 12,
        "name": "Magnesium",
        "atomicWeight": 24.305,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.6462,
        "melting": 650,
        "boiling": 1090
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 13,
        "name": "Aluminum",
        "atomicWeight": 26.981538,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.9858,
        "melting": 660.32,
        "boiling": 2519
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 14,
        "name": "Silicon",
        "atomicWeight": 28.0855,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.1517,
        "melting": 1414,
        "boiling": 2900
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 15,
        "name": "Phosphorus",
        "atomicWeight": 30.97361,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 10.4867,
        "melting": 44.2,
        "boiling": 280.5
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 16,
        "name": "Sulfur",
        "atomicWeight": 32.065,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 10.36,
        "melting": 115.21,
        "boiling": 444.72
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 17,
        "name": "Chlorine",
        "atomicWeight": 35.453,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 12.9676,
        "melting": -101.5,
        "boiling": -34.04
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 18,
        "name": "Argon",
        "atomicWeight": 39.948,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 15.7596,
        "melting": -189.3,
        "boiling": -185.8
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 19,
        "name": "Potassium",
        "atomicWeight": 39.0983,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 4.3407,
        "melting": 63.38,
        "boiling": 759
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 20,
        "name": "Calcium",
        "atomicWeight": 40.078,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.1132,
        "melting": 842,
        "boiling": 1484
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 21,
        "name": "Scandium",
        "atomicWeight": 44.95591,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.5615,
        "melting": 1541,
        "boiling": 2830
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 22,
        "name": "Titanium",
        "atomicWeight": 47.867,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.8281,
        "melting": 1668,
        "boiling": 3287
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 23,
        "name": "Vanadium",
        "atomicWeight": 50.9415,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.7462,
        "melting": 1910,
        "boiling": 3407
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 24,
        "name": "Chromium",
        "atomicWeight": 51.9961,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.7665,
        "melting": 1907,
        "boiling": 2671
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 25,
        "name": "Manganese",
        "atomicWeight": 54.938049,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.434,
        "melting": 1246,
        "boiling": 2061
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 26,
        "name": "Iron",
        "atomicWeight": 55.845,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.9024,
        "melting": 1538,
        "boiling": 2861
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 27,
        "name": "Cobalt",
        "atomicWeight": 58.9332,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.881,
        "melting": 1495,
        "boiling": 2927
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 28,
        "name": "Nickel",
        "atomicWeight": 58.6934,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.6398,
        "melting": 1455,
        "boiling": 2913
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 29,
        "name": "Copper",
        "atomicWeight": 63.546,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.7264,
        "melting": 1084.62,
        "boiling": 2927
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 30,
        "name": "Zinc",
        "atomicWeight": 65.409,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 9.3942,
        "melting": 419.53,
        "boiling": 907
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 31,
        "name": "Gallium",
        "atomicWeight": 69.723,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.9993,
        "melting": 29.76,
        "boiling": 2204
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 32,
        "name": "Germanium",
        "atomicWeight": 72.64,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.8994,
        "melting": 938.3,
        "boiling": 2820
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 33,
        "name": "Arsenic",
        "atomicWeight": 74.9216,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 9.7886,
        "melting": 817,
        "boiling": 614
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 34,
        "name": "Selenium",
        "atomicWeight": 78.96,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 9.7524,
        "melting": 221,
        "boiling": 685
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 35,
        "name": "Bromine",
        "atomicWeight": 79.904,
        "phase": "Liquid",
        "ionization": 11.8138,
        "melting": -7.3,
        "boiling": 59
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 36,
        "name": "Krypton",
        "atomicWeight": 83.798,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 13.9996,
        "melting": -157.36,
        "boiling": -153.22
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 37,
        "name": "Rubidium",
        "atomicWeight": 85.4678,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 4.1771,
        "melting": 39.31,
        "boiling": 688
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 38,
        "name": "Strontium",
        "atomicWeight": 87.62,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.6949,
        "melting": 777,
        "boiling": 1382
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 39,
        "name": "Yttrium",
        "atomicWeight": 88.90585,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.2173,
        "melting": 1526,
        "boiling": 3345
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 40,
        "name": "Zirconium",
        "atomicWeight": 91.224,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.6339,
        "melting": 1855,
        "boiling": 4409
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 41,
        "name": "Niobium",
        "atomicWeight": 92.90638,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.7589,
        "melting": 2477,
        "boiling": 4744
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 42,
        "name": "Molybdenum",
        "atomicWeight": 95.94,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.0924,
        "melting": 2623,
        "boiling": 4639
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 43,
        "name": "Technetium",
        "atomicWeight": (98),
        "phase": "Synthetic",
        "ionization": 7.28,
        "melting": 2157,
        "boiling": 4265
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 44,
        "name": "Ruthenium",
        "atomicWeight": 101.07,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.3605,
        "melting": 2334,
        "boiling": 4150
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 45,
        "name": "Rhodium",
        "atomicWeight": 102.9055,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.4589,
        "melting": 1964,
        "boiling": 3695
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 46,
        "name": "Palladium",
        "atomicWeight": 106.42,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.3369,
        "melting": 1554.9,
        "boiling": 2963
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 47,
        "name": "Silver",
        "atomicWeight": 107.8682,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.5762,
        "melting": 961.78,
        "boiling": 2162
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 48,
        "name": "Cadmium",
        "atomicWeight": 112.411,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.9938,
        "melting": 321.07,
        "boiling": 767
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 49,
        "name": "Indium",
        "atomicWeight": 114.818,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.7864,
        "melting": 156.6,
        "boiling": 2072
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 50,
        "name": "Tin",
        "atomicWeight": 118.71,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.3439,
        "melting": 231.93,
        "boiling": 2602
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 51,
        "name": "Antimony",
        "atomicWeight": 121.76,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.6084,
        "melting": 630.63,
        "boiling": 1587
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 52,
        "name": "Tellurium",
        "atomicWeight": 127.6,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 9.0096,
        "melting": 449.51,
        "boiling": 988
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 53,
        "name": "Iodine",
        "atomicWeight": 126.90447,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 10.4513,
        "melting": 113.7,
        "boiling": 184.3
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 54,
        "name": "Xenon",
        "atomicWeight": 131.293,
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 12.1298,
        "melting": -111.8,
        "boiling": -108
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 55,
        "name": "Cesium",
        "atomicWeight": 132.90545,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 3.8939,
        "melting": 28.44,
        "boiling": 671
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 56,
        "name": "Barium",
        "atomicWeight": 137.327,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.2117,
        "melting": 727,
        "boiling": 1870
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 57,
        "name": "Lanthanum",
        "atomicWeight": 138.9055,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.5769,
        "melting": 920,
        "boiling": 3464
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 58,
        "name": "Cerium",
        "atomicWeight": 140.116,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.5387,
        "melting": 798,
        "boiling": 3360
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 59,
        "name": "Praseodymium",
        "atomicWeight": 140.90765,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.473,
        "melting": 931,
        "boiling": 3290
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 60,
        "name": "Neodymium",
        "atomicWeight": 144.24,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.525,
        "melting": 1021,
        "boiling": 3100
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 61,
        "name": "Promethium",
        "atomicWeight": (145),
        "phase": "Synthetic",
        "ionization": 5.582,
        "melting": 1100,
        "boiling": 3000
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 62,
        "name": "Samarium",
        "atomicWeight": 150.36,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.6437,
        "melting": 1072,
        "boiling": 1803
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 63,
        "name": "Europium",
        "atomicWeight": 151.964,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.6704,
        "melting": 822,
        "boiling": 1527
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 64,
        "name": "Gadolinium",
        "atomicWeight": 157.25,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.1498,
        "melting": 1313,
        "boiling": 3250
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 65,
        "name": "Terbium",
        "atomicWeight": 158.92534,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.8638,
        "melting": 1356,
        "boiling": 3230
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 66,
        "name": "Dysprosium",
        "atomicWeight": 162.5,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.9389,
        "melting": 1412,
        "boiling": 2567
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 67,
        "name": "Holmium",
        "atomicWeight": 164.93032,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.0215,
        "melting": 1474,
        "boiling": 2700
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 68,
        "name": "Erbium",
        "atomicWeight": 167.259,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.1077,
        "melting": 1497,
        "boiling": 2868
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 69,
        "name": "Thulium",
        "atomicWeight": 168.93421,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.1843,
        "melting": 1545,
        "boiling": 1950
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 70,
        "name": "Ytterbium",
        "atomicWeight": 173.04,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.2542,
        "melting": 819,
        "boiling": 1196
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 71,
        "name": "Lutetium",
        "atomicWeight": 174.967,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.4259,
        "melting": 1663,
        "boiling": 3402
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 72,
        "name": "Hafnium",
        "atomicWeight": 178.49,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.8251,
        "melting": 2233,
        "boiling": 4603
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 73,
        "name": "Tantalum",
        "atomicWeight": 180.9479,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.5496,
        "melting": 3017,
        "boiling": 5458
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 74,
        "name": "Tungsten",
        "atomicWeight": 183.84,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.864,
        "melting": 3422,
        "boiling": 5555
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 75,
        "name": "Rhenium",
        "atomicWeight": 186.207,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.8335,
        "melting": 3186,
        "boiling": 5596
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 76,
        "name": "Osmium",
        "atomicWeight": 190.23,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.4382,
        "melting": 3033,
        "boiling": 5012
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 77,
        "name": "Iridium",
        "atomicWeight": 192.217,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.967,
        "melting": 2466,
        "boiling": 4428
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 78,
        "name": "Platinum",
        "atomicWeight": 195.078,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.9588,
        "melting": 1768.3,
        "boiling": 3825
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 79,
        "name": "Gold",
        "atomicWeight": 196.96655,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 9.2255,
        "melting": 1064.18,
        "boiling": 2856
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 80,
        "name": "Mercury",
        "atomicWeight": 200.59,
        "phase": "Liquid",
        "ionization": 10.4375,
        "melting": -38.83,
        "boiling": 356.73
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 81,
        "name": "Thallium",
        "atomicWeight": 204.3833,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.1082,
        "melting": 304,
        "boiling": 1473
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 82,
        "name": "Lead",
        "atomicWeight": 207.2,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.4167,
        "melting": 327.46,
        "boiling": 1749
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 83,
        "name": "Bismuth",
        "atomicWeight": 208.98038,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 7.2855,
        "melting": 271.3,
        "boiling": 1564
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 84,
        "name": "Polonium",
        "atomicWeight": (209),
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 8.414,
        "melting": 254,
        "boiling": 962
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 86,
        "name": "Radon",
        "atomicWeight": (222),
        "phase": "Gas",
        "ionization": 10.7485,
        "melting": -71,
        "boiling": -61.7
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 88,
        "name": "Radium",
        "atomicWeight": (226),
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.2784,
        "melting": 700,
        "boiling": 1737
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 89,
        "name": "Actinium",
        "atomicWeight": (227),
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.17,
        "melting": 1050,
        "boiling": 3200
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 90,
        "name": "Thorium",
        "atomicWeight": 232.0381,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.3067,
        "melting": 1750,
        "boiling": 4820
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 91,
        "name": "Protactinium",
        "atomicWeight": 231.03588,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 5.89,
        "melting": 1572,
        "boiling": 4000
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 92,
        "name": "Uranium",
        "atomicWeight": 238.02891,
        "phase": "Solid",
        "ionization": 6.1941,
        "melting": 1135,
        "boiling": 3927
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 93,
        "name": "Neptunium",
        "atomicWeight": (237),
        "phase": "Synthetic",
        "ionization": 6.2657,
        "melting": 644,
        "boiling": 4000
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 94,
        "name": "Plutonium",
        "atomicWeight": (244),
        "phase": "Synthetic",
        "ionization": 6.026,
        "melting": 640,
        "boiling": 3230
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 95,
        "name": "Americium",
        "atomicWeight": (243),
        "phase": "Synthetic",
        "ionization": 5.9738,
        "melting": 1176,
        "boiling": 2011
      }, {
        "atomicNumber": 96,
        "name": "Curium",
        "atomicWeight": (247),
        "phase": "Synthetic",
        "ionization": 5.9914,
        "melting": 1345,
        "boiling": 3110
      }]
    };
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="chemistryApp">
  <h1>Chemistry Controller</h1>
  <div class="container" id="ngChem1" ng-controller="chemistryController">
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="elementName" />
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="element in periodic.elements | filter:elementName">{{element.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```